# Return a casbah type findOne in a method

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I'm making a system using scala and I make a method that return a "findOne".

Follow my code

```
def findOneByField(field:String, value:String): Any = {
  val search: DBObject = MongoDBObject(field -> value)
  return User.coll.findOne(search).get
}
```

I put the return type like Any because I cannot make equals MongoDb findOne return type.

I want to make this

```
val o = MongoDBObject("email"->"myemail@gmail.com")
findOneByField("email","myemail@gmail.com") == coll.findOne(o)
Boolean True
```

But if I get the type of coll.findOne, I receive this type:

```
res10: Option[com.myapptest.models.User.coll.T] = Some({ "_id" : { "$oid" : "57828cfe3b931047e1bb5455"} , "email" : "myemail@gmail.com" , "name" : "My Name" , "id" : "34863249182"})
```

I have no idea how return the same findOne in the method.
Could you help me?

Thanks! xD

Comment: What is `User`? And what type does `User.coll.findOne(search)` have?

Comment: I might be missing something but isn't it that `findOneByField("email","myemail@gmail.com") == coll.findOne(o)` not equal simply because you are calling `.get` inside of `findOneByField `? So `findOneByField("email","myemail@gmail.com") == coll.findOne(o).get` should be true.